# Block operations on Sparse Matrices- Eigen Toolbox- C++

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

```
Block operations for sparse matrices - Eigen Toolbox - C++ 


#include "Eigen/Dense"
#include "Eigen/Sparse"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

    int main()
    {
    MatrixXd silly(6, 3);
    silly << 0, 1, 2,
            0, 3, 0,
            2, 0, 0,
            3, 2, 1,
            0, 1, 0,
            2, 0, 0;

        SparseMatrix<double> sparse_silly,temp;
        sparse_silly= Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>(6, 3);
        temp = Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>(6, 3);
        sparse_silly = silly.sparseView();

        std::cout << "Whole Matrix" << std::endl;
        std::cout << sparse_silly << std::endl;



         temp.block(0, 0, 2, 2)=sparse_silly.block(0, 0, 2, 2);

        std::cout << "block of matrix" << std::endl;
        std::cout << temp.block(0, 0, 2, 2) << std::endl;

        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
```

In the above code, the block operations for sparse matrices are not working using Eigen toolbox. I want a assign a block from a sparse_silly to a block in  temp matrix. The output printed is zero for the temp matrix.Can anyone help me if i missed something conceptually. The recent documentation says block operations are availble for sparse matrices.

Answer (score 5):

Blocks of sparse matrices in Eigen are not all writable. Certain ones are (e.g. `.col(Index)` in a column major matrix) but the generic `.block(Index, Index, Index, Index)` is not. The [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1SparseMatrixBase.html#a3c219dd64ee201314e70a9a528619289) is quite confusing on that matter, but if you look closely, all the examples are with dense matrices and not sparse ones. The [`col()`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1SparseMatrixBase.html#ad49129f2301063ce046ae071c82610d5) documentation uses a dense matrix example as well, but if you try it, you'll see that it works.

Comment: Yes exactly... the block  assignemnt operation are not currently available in Sparse matrices.  But i can see that the block extraction is possible in sparse matrices... i mean .block() can only take as rvalue.

Any help if i can modify something in header file in a most optimzed way..

Comment: With sparse matrices, insertion can be expensive, especially if across rows in a column major matrix (not just one reservation of memory). The lack of lvalue implementation may be on purpose to prevent people from writing inefficient (but easy to write) code.