# How to add a block matrix onto a sparse matrix in Eigen

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

For example I have a 10x10 SparseMatrix A, and I want to add a 3x3 identity matrix to the upper left corner of A.

A is known to be already non-zero in those 3 entries.

If I have to add the values one by one it is ok too, but I didn't find the method to manipulate on elements of a Sparse Matrix in Eigen.

Did I miss something?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35124470/block-operations-on-sparse-matrices-eigen-toolbox-c) post. You really can't use all block operations on sparse matrices.

Comment: How about element operations? I saw there were insert methods but can I add values to certain elements?

Comment: I'm not following. What do you mean by element operations and add values to certain elements? Something like `m(i,j) += k;`?

Comment: Yes. Because I only want to add an identity matrix that isn't very large, so maybe doing operations like this can be more efficient than using column operations on the sparse matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is to apply an operation to a specific element at a time, you can use [`coeffRef`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseMatrix.html#a4386da578a119f7b500d0b22cab2de0e) like so:

```
typedef Eigen::Triplet<double> T;
std::vector<T> coefficients;
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) coefficients.push_back(T(i, i, (i % 3) + 1));

Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> A(10, 10);
A.setFromTriplets(coefficients.begin(), coefficients.end());

std::cout << A << "\n\n";

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) A.coeffRef(i,i) += 1;
std::cout << A << "\n\n";
```