# Changing a block in Eigen::SparseMatrix

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

I need to change values of a block in a sparse matrix (just the values, not the indices). The sparsity pattern remains the same. Is there an efficient way to do so? I understood that coeffRef over many elements might be expensive. Another option is constructing a new matrix, but then I need to get all the other blocks which don't change. This is also not efficient... Any Ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Depending on the access pattern you need, perhaps use an InnerIterator.  There are examples in https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html

Comment: Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35124470/block-operations-on-sparse-matrices-eigen-toolbox-c).