# Removing a row or a column from the same SparseMatrix with EIGEN

Tags: eigen, eigen3

I'm a bit in trouble with something which is probably very simple.

I'm looking for a way to delete rows or columns on the SAME SparseMatrix.

I'm working with SparseMatrix in RowMajor "mode", to delete rows I'm doing :

```
void removeRow(unsigned int rowID, SparseMatrix<short int, RowMajor> & toDealWith)
{
    for (unsigned int i = rowID; i < toDealWith.rows() - 1; i++){
        toDealWith.row(i) = toDealWith.row(i + 1);
    }
    toDealWith.conservativeResize(toDealWith.rows() - 1, toDealWith.cols());
}
```

Innocently, I was expecting this to work :

```
void removeCol(unsigned int colID, SparseMatrix<short int, RowMajor> & toDealWith)
{
    for (unsigned int i = colID; i < toDealWith.cols() - 1; i++){
        toDealWith.col(i) = toDealWith.col(i + 1);
    }
    toDealWith.conservativeResize(toDealWith.rows(), toDealWith.cols() - 1);
}
```

But this is not compiling on VS2013, due to :

```
error C2666: 'Eigen::BlockImpl<XprType,-1,1,false,Eigen::internal::traits<Derived>::StorageKind>::operator =' : 2 overloads have similar conversions    ...
```

After some investigation, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35124470/block-operations-on-sparse-matrices-eigen-toolbox-c), which, I guess, is the problem here.

I tried different ways to achieve this, but none of them worked.

My question here is, since the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35124470/block-operations-on-sparse-matrices-eigen-toolbox-c) is 1 year old, did I missed some updates making the operations of row deletion and column deletion on the same SparseMatrix available?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you didn't miss anything. It's an either/or situation, not both.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this actually? I tried to create a ColumnMajor matrix copying my RowMajor matrix, and then use the .col functions to swap columns but still, since the column was "sparse" it's throwing a read access violation error. Well, I guess the overkill solution is to iterate over the SparseMatrix<RM> to create a new SparseMatrix<RM> without the column we want to delete, but it is not really efficient.